# How i can filter multiple columns with same condition in r

Tags: r

I have dataset like as mentioned below. I want to filter out all the values  between 20 and 40 and want to apply it to all the columns :

```
a. 23,45,57,87
b. 34,45,23,25
c. 34,56,67,87
```

expected results :

```
a. 23,0,0,0
b. 0,34,23,25
c. 34, 0, 0, 0
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Probably a duplicate. But I'm going to jump on and provide an answer, but I know it is not the most ideal way.

```
a <- c(23,45,57,87)
b <- c(34,45,23,25)
c <- c(34,56,67,87)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
df %>% mutate(a = replace(a, !a %in% 20:40, 0)) %>% mutate(b = replace(b, !b %in% 20:40, 0))%>% mutate(c = replace(c, !c %in% 20:40, 0))
```

This serves the purpose, although it does violate the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1):

With `mutate_all` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_all(df, funs(replace(., . < 20 | 40 < ., 0)))
```

**Result:**

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1 23  0  0  0
2 34  0 23 25
3 34  0  0  0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(23, 34, 34), V2 = c(45, 45, 56), V3 = c(57, 
23, 67), V4 = c(87, 25, 87)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"
), row.names = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score -1):

A `base R` option would be

```
df[df < 20 | df > 40] <- 0
```

### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(23, 45, 57, 87), b = c(34, 45, 23, 25), 
 c = c(34, 56, 67, 87)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```